# How to make Winrar look at XPI files as a RAR file?

Tags: windows-7, shell, windows-registry, winrar

I think it might be possible editing some settings on the registry. Can anyone tell me what I have to edit? So the shell methods will be the same for RAR and XPI files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Winrar's `Options > Settings > Integration` tab. Inside the "User defined archive extensions" box, type `.XPI` and click OK. Windows 7 will request your permission to change system settings. Click Yes and you're done.

Comment: Wow, perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. You're welcome.